# a4j:support onchange event not firing

Tags: java, seam, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to rerender a second dropdown when i change the value in the first one.
But nothing happens when I click and change the value in the first drop down.
Have I missed any crucial part?

**My xhtml:**

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{adminBean.currentLeadCategory}" required="true" styleClass="formfield fpgeo" style="width:20em;margin-right:20px;">
        <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{adminBean.currentLeadCategoryChanged()}"
 reRender="componentToReRender"/>
        <s:selectItems value="#{leadCategories}" var="leadCategory" label="#{leadCategory.name}" noSelectionLabel="Choose Category"/>
        <s:convertEntity/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

<a4j:outputPanel id="componentToReRenderWrapper">

    <h:selectOneMenu id="componentToReRender" value="#{adminBean.currentCounty}"
 styleClass="formfield fpgeo" style="width:20em;margin-right:20px;">
        <s:selectItems value="#{adminBean.counties}" var="county" label="#{county.name}" noSelectionLabel="choose"/>
        <s:convertEntity/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
<h:messages/>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

**My bean:**

```
@AutoCreate
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("adminBean")
@MeasureCalls
@Restrict("#{s:hasRole('admin') or s:hasRole('sales')}")
public class AdminBean implements Serializable {

    private LeadCategory currentLeadCategory;
    private List<County> counties = new ArrayList<County>();
    private County currentCounty;

@Factory(value = "leadCategories", autoCreate = true, scope = ScopeType.SESSION)
    public List<LeadCategory> fetchLeadCategories() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select l from LeadCategory l");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

public LeadCategory getCurrentLeadCategory() {
        return currentLeadCategory;
    }

    public void setCurrentLeadCategory(LeadCategory currentLeadCategory) {
        this.currentLeadCategory = currentLeadCategory;
    }

    public County getCurrentCounty() {
        return currentCounty;
    }

    public void setCurrentCounty(County currentCounty) {
        this.currentCounty = currentCounty;
    }

    public void currentLeadCategoryChanged() {
        this.loadCountiesForCategory();
    }

    public List<County> getCounties() {
        return counties;
    }

    public void setCounties(List<County> counties) {
        this.counties = counties;
    }

    public void loadCountiesForCategory(){
        if(currentLeadCategory == null){
            counties = new ArrayList<County>();
        }
        counties = new ArrayList<County>(currentLeadCategory.getCounties());
    }


}
```

EDIT 1:

If i check firebug i get an error:
Timestamp: 7/19/12 4:14:44 PM
Error: ReferenceError: A4J is not defined
Source File: `http://localhost:8080/admin/admin.seam?cid=11`
Line: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found the problem! Major crazyness going on here. Someone has set LoadScriptStrategy
param to NONE in the web.xml. This makes that the framework.pack.js and ui.pack.js is **NOT** loading.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
<param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Found this page at [docs.jboss](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Portal_Platform/5.0/html/Reference_Guide/sect-Reference_Guide-Bridge_Configuration-RichFaces_Setup_and_Configuration_Options.html)

> If you use the "NONE" strategy, you must include the following scripts
>   in your portlet or portal page header. If you are using JBoss Portal,
>   you can add this to the jboss-portlet.xml file.

Added `<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js"/>`
to my header template and viola everything works like a charm.

I love my job =)

Answer (score 0):

I can see clearly that your xhtml has an ending tag `</a4j:outputPanel>` but no starting tag: `<a4j:outputPanel>`
If you rearrange your tags it will work.